# Print server - Single print-queue with multipe routing

Tags: pdf, printing, raspberry-pi

I'm working on web-app (.net Core 6) which is generating two types of PDF documents. First one should print on dot-matrix printer (Paper format Fanfold 8 1/2" x 12") and the second should print on ordinary laser printer (A4). Both printers are on network, accessing through TCP/IP Port (IP adress).

Note: Since it is web-app, browser can not access system printer due to security.

User story:

- Click on print document 1 -> Hit enter (or similar confirm) -> send print job to Printer 1 (without manualy selecting printer).
- Click on print document 2 -> Hit enter (or similar confirm) -> send print job to Printer 2 (without manualy selecting printer).

I want to print around 400 document-pairs/hour so it is not possible each time set the printer manually in the print dialog.

- Is this even possible? How to perform this type of logic on RP?
- Can you suggest me, or at least point me to some direction?
- Are there any tools that can do this out of the box?

ref: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=270930

After some research, I found that best possible solution would be to set-up **Raspberry-Pi print server**. However, I am completely new to this. I need the server to perform some logic and send the job to correct printer. Printer settings (like paper size) will be adjusted only from the default printer preferences. In browser printing dialog it will set printer just something like "Rasp-Pi Print server"